# how to animate a view as a webview will scroll in android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview and a button at the bottom of the layout.
I want to animate this button as my webview will be scrolled.
But I am not able to track that which functions is calling when I scrolls my webview.

Actually I want to track webview scrolling, i am not able to know that which callback function is called when I scroll our webview.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Use this wonderful library : [Nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

You will animate your `Button` and your `WebView` like this :

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myButton, "rotationY", 0, 360),   /* rotate Y  coordonates of your button from 0 to 360 degre */
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myWebView, "translationY", 0, 500), /* translate Y coordonates of WebView from top to 500 */

);
set.setDuration(3 * 1000).start(); /* A delay of 3 seconds for this animation */
```

If you want to add a listner :

```
set.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Its ok but actually I want to track webview scrolling, i am not able to know that which callback function is called when I scroll our webview.

Comment: The issue is that when to run this code, this code must be done when the webview scrolls and I m not able to track webview's scrolling. I wants to know that which callback function I need to override to track scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Either subclass the WebView and the override [onScrollChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) (don't forget to call super!) or use a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) if you can't subclass for some reason.

```
class MyWebView extends android.webkit.WebView {
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged (int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        // Your code here.
    }
}
```